# How to deploy django rest API with dlib predictor on heroku?

Tags: heroku, django-rest-framework, deployment, dlib

I'm writing my faceswap restAPI that use dlib to predict face landmarks. So I tried to deploy my project to Heroku and I can't do this becase I'm getting in Release phase.

```
File "/app/api/faceswap.py", line 39, in <module>
predictor = dlib.shape_predictor(PREDICTOR_PATH)
RuntimeError: Unable to open shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks-1.dat
```

As you can see I'm getting the runtime error about predictor file with ".dat" extension.
Please tell me how can I fix this error or advise other ways to deploy.
Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

So, all you need to do is check the path to file on heroku cli after deploying and change it in your code.

```
(It was) PREDICTOR_PATH = r"C:\RestAPI_v2\shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat"
(Solution) PREDICTOR_PATH = r"/app/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat"
```